# How to resovle problem view composer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, service-provider

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
     // ...
     App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,
     App\Http\View\Composers\AdComposer::class,
],
```

**app/Providers/ViewServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'layouts.sidebar', 'App\Http\View\Composers\AdComposer'
        );
    }
}
```

**app/Http/View/Composers/AdComposer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use App\Ad;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class AdComposer
{

    protected $ads;

    public function __construct(Ad $ads)
    {
        $this->ads = $ads;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('ads', $this->ads);
    }
}
```

**my problem is:**

> TypeError Argument 1 passed to
> App\Http\View\Composers\AdComposer::__construct() must be an instance
> of App\Ad, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called
> in
> E:\appoo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php
> on line 208

**How to resovle this problem and pass $ads to view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `AdComposer` from the providers array.

The docs state:

> Remember, **if you create a new service provider** to contain your view composer registrations, you will need to add the service provider to the providers array in the config/app.php configuration file.

It does  not tell you to add your composer to the providers array.

Also, if you type-hint `App\Ad` you will get an empty instance just so you're aware.

Comment: i removed AdComposer from provider array and but ViewServiceProvider remains in this array. but now show error: Target class [view.engine.resolver] does not exist.

Comment: @MehdiJalali make sure your `viewServiceProvider` is the last entry in the provider array and make sure `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class` is still in the array above your entry.

If this doesn't help i'll need the full error backtrace

Comment: thanks. this problem is resolved but now new problem: use foreach $ads as $ad and use $ad->title show "non-object error". i use foreach ($ads as $ad) {{ dd($ad) }} endforeach and only show true.

Comment: @MehdiJalali That's because you're trying to dependency inject a model through your composer's constructor, it's not going to return an array and won't work that way, i'm not sure what exactly you're tying to do but if you want to show all ads just use `$view->with('ads', Ad::all())` and remove `$this->ads` entirely.

Comment: thankssssssssss. change `$view->with('ads', Ad::all())` with `$this->ads` and return value in view.